# Targeting a div to reveal content jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hide, show

I'm trying to target a div to reveal the content of a div when clicked. This is works on either the last div when in a group of 2 or the first and last in a group of 3. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Find my code below.

I'm also making the divs smaller using jquery and then appending a div onto them to reveal and hide the information.

Html

```
<div class="section_hidereveal">
    <div class="section">CONTENT GOES HERE </div>
    <div class="show">
        <a class="showaction">View this section </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var $tArray = $('.section');
    $tArray.each(function(){
        if ($(this).height() > 600) {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
            $('<div class="show"><a class="showaction">View this section</a></div>').insertAfter(this); 
        }
        $(".show a").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.section_hidereveal').find('.section').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here is a link to my site as well.

[Link to site](http://louisbennett.net/?doingdebate=17-residential-trips)

Comment: It works on last three div's on your site.

Comment: It isn't working for me on example 2? Could this be a browser issue?